# Computing Hamming weight, also called popcount in Java?

Tags: java, c++, nlp, computer-vision, porting

I am not sure how to translate this from C++ to Java.
It is a function that computes the Hamming weight.

```
/** This is popcount_3() from:
 * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight */
unsigned int popcnt32(uint32_t n) const
{
    n -= ((n >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    n = (n & 0x33333333) + ((n >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    return (((n + (n >> 4))& 0xF0F0F0F)* 0x1010101) >> 24;
}
```

More concretely, I don't know what to use instead of uint32_t,
and if I use that type whatever it is, can I just leave the rest
code unchanged?

Thanks

Comment: For one, there is no equivalent of `uint32_t` in Java, you'd have to use `long`.

Comment: Oli well I am not sure what to try really. It seems like so many things can go wrong.

Comment: @fge: An `int` should work fine, although some of the operators may need to change a little...

Comment: Change the first line to `static int popcnt32(int n)`. The rest can stay as is, although using `>>>` instead of `>>` in some places could be considered cleaner.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's implemented for you in `Integer.bitCount(int i)`